C program not scanning and printing values correctly after fgets()
I made C program containing a structure made of a string called name and int called marks.  The program is supposed to take inputs name and marks for two structures man1 and man2 and then print them.
Here's my code:
#include<stdio.h>
struct stud
{
    char name[50];
    int marks;
};

int main()
{
    struct stud man1;
    struct stud man2;
    printf("Enter the name and marks of first man\n");
    fgets(man1.name,20,stdin);
    scanf("%d",&man1.marks);
    printf("Enter the name and marks of second man\n");
    fgets(man2.name,20,stdin);
    scanf("%d",&man2.marks);
    printf("Output\n");
    printf("%s\n%d\n%s\n%d\n",man1.name,man1.marks,man2.name,man2.marks);

return 0;    
}

During execution the program is expected to first prompt for input, then take the name and marks as input, prompt again for the second input and take the name and marks as in input and finally print the entered values.
What actually happens is after entering name and marks of man1 when the name of man2 is entered, it does not take the input for the marks of man2 and instead jumps to printing the values, prints the name and marks of man1 correctly but does not print the name for man2 and prints 508 at the end of code everything I run it
The output console looks like this :
Enter the name and marks of first man
sid
1
Enter the name and marks of second man
dan
Output
sid
1
508
Tried using clang, gcc and online compilers and I use VSC. Everytime I build the exe file using gcc the number printed at the end changes, but it remains the same if I use execute the exe file without building it again.Using clang and online compilers have the same output except the number printed at the end changes to 0.
Why is it happening and how can I fix this?

scanf("%d",&man2.marks); is most likely leaving a newline in stdin. Which fgets(man2.name,20,stdin); then reads.

why would the scanf read first then the fgets() when fegst() is called first and then scanf() ?

Because fgets and scanf are different. fgets will read up to and including the new line. scanf reads up to white space then stops, leaving the white space.

https://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html might be educational.

@Siddhanta Mallick Instead of using fgets you can also use scanf as for example
scanf( " %49[^\n]", man1.name);. Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white spaces.

How to read / parse input in C FAQ

Generally, don't mix fgets() with scanf().  Use fgets() to read data and sscanf() (two letters 's') to parse what it reads.  This avoids most of the confusion over line endings.  It also allows you to try parsing the line multiple times, which can be beneficial, and also gives you the complete line to report errors, which is usually beneficial.  Using scanf() (one letter 's') means that you can't rescan data that it misinterprets.
